# /bin/sh: /bin: Is a directory

Tags: linux, gcc

I am compiling by code using make command on centos (rhel 7)_ , with gcc 7.1 , but got stuck in the following error:

/bin/sh: /bin: Is a directory

which sh returns /usr/bin/sh

Comment: have you tried cd bin ?

Comment: cd /bin is a directoy

Comment: then cd bin, after that ./sh

Comment: by executting ./sh i am in sh shell , now ran build command still got the same error : /bin/sh: /bin: Is a directory

Comment: After cd bin, then type `./sh` to execute your .sh file

Comment: i have executed my .sh file  i got "sh-4.2$ " on shell , then i changed my directory - where the code is presnt using cd then ran make command , but still got the error

Comment: post the complete directory

Comment: my code is residing in /home/mycode/...

Comment: Not a clear description, Can you post a minimal makefile to repro or a clear description

Comment: command to build : make all

Comment: Another build error :undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::regex_error using gcc7.1 . i have bosst libraries for gcc4.8.2

Comment: can't understand what you trying to achieve

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named "[What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)" and "[What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)". Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Compiling some source code with gcc-7.1 , rest code is precompiled with gcc 4.8.2 . Are the binaries of gcc 4.8.2 and gcc 7.1 compatible

Answer (score 0):

This means one of the make commands try to execute /bin and cannot (since it is a directory). You then have an incomplete path towards an expected executable file.

You can read your makefile and find the probably missing variable to complete the path.

You can also run `make V=1` to have a verbose output and see where the error lies.